# Haskell: writing a function such that it can be lifted to work on lists

Tags: haskell, lifting

I have the following 2 functions:

```
import qualified Data.Text as T

noneOnEmptyA :: T.Text -> T.Text
noneOnEmptyA txt | T.null txt = "None."
                 | otherwise  = txt


noneOnEmptyB :: [T.Text] -> [T.Text]
noneOnEmptyB txts | null txts = ["None."]
                  | otherwise = txts
```

Is it possible to write a single function that 1) accomplishes what `noneOnEmptyA` does, and 2) can be lifted such that it accomplishes what `noneOnEmptyB` does? The crux of the problem seems to be that `noneOnEmptyA` checks for empty text, while `noneOnEmptyB` checks for an empty list; however, `noneOnEmptyA` lifted so as to operate on lists (as in `fmap noneOnEmptyA` returning type `[T.Text]`) checks for empty text inside the list, rather than checking whether or not the list itself is empty.

Comment: The `null` check *may* be done using something like `Foldable`'s [`null`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:null) method. But then the problem is how to return the correct value in the empty case...

Comment: `Text` is not a `Foldable` - as it is no container how would you write `foldMap`, except for `fold = foldl` and `foldMap = undefined`, which is a bad idea

Comment: @epsilonhalbe, it's true that `Text` cannot be `Foldable`, but not for the reasons you give. The real problem is that only types of kind `* -> *` can be `Foldable`, and `Text` has kind `*`.

Comment: @epsilonhalb, consider `data T :: * -> * where T :: Text -> T Char`. You can write a perfectly legitimate and sensible `Foldable` instance for `T`.

Comment: the-konapie, why do you want such a function? It seems rather strange.

Comment: @dfeur, I want to use these functions to generate text that will be shown to the user of my game. I have use cases for both functions and was wondering if I could somehow write a single function that can be used in both cases.

Comment: @dfeuer that was what I was trying to say with container, I am still not precise enough, sometimes - but the kind `* -> * was what I had in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one thing you could do is introduce a typeclass `Nullable`

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Stackoverflow where

import           Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T
import           Data.Monoid
import           Data.String

class Nullable a where
    isNull :: a -> Bool

instance Nullable Text where
    isNull = T.null

instance IsString a => IsString [a] where
    fromString str = [fromString str]
```

then you can write your function

```
noneOnEmpty :: (Nullable a, IsString a, Monoid a) => a -> a
noneOnEmpty a | isNull a = "None" <> mempty
              | otherwise = a
```

### Update

As @DanielWagner points out - the `Monoid`/`mempty`/`<>` part is not necessary

```
noneOnEmpty :: (Nullable a, IsString a) => a -> a
noneOnEmpty a | isNull a = "None"
              | otherwise = a
```

Comment: What's the `<> mempty` for?

Comment: it is from the time when I didn't think correctly of the `isString` method

Comment: What does the `IsString a => IsString [a]` instance get you? Why not just: `instance Nullable [a] where isNull = null`?

Comment: @the-konapie The extra `IsString` instance is so that `"None"` can be given the type `[Text]`.